Unresoved import on function from lib.rs called from another module
I have the following project structure:
src
├── display
│  └── mod.rs
├── lib.rs
├── main.rs
└── tetromino
   ├── characters.rs
   ├── line.rs
   ├── mod.rs
   └── tetromino.rs

And in lib.rs  I have this function:
pub fn move_to_built(
    tetromino: &mut Tetromino,
    built_tetrominoes: &mut [[TetrominoCharacter; WIDTH]; HEIGHT],
) {
    if tetromino.stationary {
        for character in &tetromino.first_line.characters {
            let x = character.x;
            let y = character.y;
            built_tetrominoes[y as usize][x as usize] = *character;
        }
        for character in &tetromino.second_line.characters {
            let x = character.x;
            let y = character.y;
            built_tetrominoes[y as usize][x as usize] = *character;
        }
        for character in &tetromino.third_line.characters {
            let x = character.x;
            let y = character.y;
            built_tetrominoes[y as usize][x as usize] = *character;
        }
        for character in &tetromino.fourth_line.characters {
            let x = character.x;
            let y = character.y;
            built_tetrominoes[y as usize][x as usize] = *character;
        }
    }
}

And in dispay/mod.rs  I'm calling it in this function
use crate::move_to_built;
use crate::Tetromino;
use crate::TetrominoCharacter;

pub fn display_screen(...) {
    move_to_built(current_tetromino, built_tetroinoes);
    ...
}       

Yet I'm getting the following error:
unresolved import `crate::move_to_built`
no `move_to_built` in the root

Here is my main.rs
use std::io::Read;

extern crate termion;
use std::io::{stdout, Write};
use termion::raw::IntoRawMode;
use termion::{async_stdin, clear};

mod display;

use rust_tetris::tetromino;
use rust_tetris::tetromino::characters::TetrominoCharacter;
use rust_tetris::tetromino::tetromino::Tetromino;
use rust_tetris::{run, GameConfig};

const WIDTH: usize = 12; // 2 more to account for the borders
const HEIGHT: usize = 40;

/* Game loop */

fn main() {
    let mut screen: [[&str; WIDTH]; HEIGHT] = [[""; WIDTH]; HEIGHT];
    let mut unrendered_tetrominoes_list: Tetromino = Tetromino::blank_tetromino(0);

    let mut game_borders: [[bool; WIDTH]; HEIGHT + 1] = [[false; WIDTH]; HEIGHT + 1];
    for x in 0..WIDTH {
        game_borders[HEIGHT][x] = true;
    }

    // When the tetrominoes' stationary state is reached, they are added to the built_tetrominoes array
    // and removed from the unredered_tetrominoes_list
    //
    // The built_tetrominoes array is used to check for collisions with the tetrominoes that have already
    // been built. Also, the built_tetrominoes array is used to render the tetrominoes that have already
    // been built and to handle the scoring system.
    //
    // Also helps in reducing the number of computations per second needed to render moving tetrominoes as the unredered_tetrominoes_list reduces in size

    let built_tetrominoes: [[TetrominoCharacter; WIDTH]; HEIGHT] =
        [[TetrominoCharacter::default(); WIDTH]; HEIGHT];

    display::create_screen(&mut screen);
    tetromino::create_tetronimo(&mut unrendered_tetrominoes_list);

    let mut stdout = stdout().into_raw_mode().unwrap();
    let stdin = async_stdin().bytes();

    writeln!(stdout, "{}{}", clear::All, termion::cursor::Hide).unwrap();

    let game_config = GameConfig {
        screen,
        current_tetromino: unrendered_tetrominoes_list,
        game_borders,
        built_tetrominoes,
        stdout,
        stdin,
    };

    run(game_config);
}

And my lib.rs
const WIDTH: usize = 12; // 2 more to account for the borders
const HEIGHT: usize = 40;

use std::io::Bytes;

extern crate termion;
use std::io::Write;
use termion::AsyncReader;

use std::thread;
use std::time::Duration;

use std::sync::mpsc;

pub mod tetromino;

use crate::tetromino::characters::TetrominoCharacter;
use crate::tetromino::tetromino::Tetromino;

pub mod display;

pub struct GameConfig<'a> {
    pub screen: [[&'a str; WIDTH]; HEIGHT],
    pub current_tetromino: Tetromino,
    pub game_borders: [[bool; WIDTH]; HEIGHT + 1],
    pub built_tetrominoes: [[TetrominoCharacter; WIDTH]; HEIGHT],
    pub stdout: termion::raw::RawTerminal<std::io::Stdout>,
    pub stdin: Bytes<AsyncReader>,
}

pub fn run(mut game_config: GameConfig) {
    let mut score: u32 = 0;

    display::display_screen(
        &game_config.screen,
        &mut game_config.current_tetromino,
        &mut game_config.stdout,
        &mut game_config.built_tetrominoes,
        score,
    );

    let (tx, rx) = mpsc::channel();
    let mut movement_counter: i32 = 1;

    // Spanws a thread that handles updating movement_counters and sends
    // true when the tetromino's y position should go down by one following the game logic
    thread::spawn(move || loop {
        thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(100));

        if movement_counter % 2 == 0 {
            tx.send(true).unwrap();
        } else {
            tx.send(false).unwrap();
        }

        movement_counter += 1;
    });

    loop {
        write!(game_config.stdout, "{}", termion::clear::CurrentLine).unwrap();

        let b = game_config.stdin.next();

        if let Some(Ok(b'q')) = b {
            break;
        }
        if let Some(Ok(b'a')) = b {
            game_config
                .current_tetromino
                .move_tetromino(-1, 0, &mut game_config.game_borders);

            display::display_screen(
                &game_config.screen,
                &mut game_config.current_tetromino,
                &mut game_config.stdout,
                &mut game_config.built_tetrominoes,
                score,
            );
        }
        if let Some(Ok(b'd')) = b {
            game_config
                .current_tetromino
                .move_tetromino(1, 0, &mut game_config.game_borders);

            display::display_screen(
                &game_config.screen,
                &mut game_config.current_tetromino,
                &mut game_config.stdout,
                &mut game_config.built_tetrominoes,
                score,
            );
        }
        if let Some(Ok(b'r')) = b {
            game_config
                .current_tetromino
                .rotate(90, &mut game_config.game_borders);

            display::display_screen(
                &game_config.screen,
                &mut game_config.current_tetromino,
                &mut game_config.stdout,
                &mut game_config.built_tetrominoes,
                score,
            );
        }
        if let Some(Ok(b's')) = b {
            game_config
                .current_tetromino
                .move_tetromino(0, 1, &mut game_config.game_borders);

            display::display_screen(
                &game_config.screen,
                &mut game_config.current_tetromino,
                &mut game_config.stdout,
                &mut game_config.built_tetrominoes,
                score,
            );
        }
        thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(1));

        if !game_config.current_tetromino.stationary {
            tetromino::create_tetronimo(&mut game_config.current_tetromino);
            break;
        }

        if rx.recv() == Ok(true) {
            game_config
                .current_tetromino
                .move_tetromino(0, 1, &mut game_config.game_borders);
        }

        display::display_screen(
            &game_config.screen,
            &mut game_config.current_tetromino,
            &mut game_config.stdout,
            &mut game_config.built_tetrominoes,
            score,
        );

        move_to_built(
            &mut game_config.current_tetromino,
            &mut game_config.built_tetrominoes,
        );

        check_complete_line(&mut game_config.built_tetrominoes, &mut score);

        remake_gameborders(
            &mut game_config.game_borders,
            &mut game_config.built_tetrominoes,
        );

        game_config.stdout.flush().unwrap();
    }
}

pub fn move_to_built(
    tetromino: &mut Tetromino,
    built_tetrominoes: &mut [[TetrominoCharacter; WIDTH]; HEIGHT],
) {
    if tetromino.stationary {
        for character in &tetromino.first_line.characters {
            let x = character.x;
            let y = character.y;
            built_tetrominoes[y as usize][x as usize] = *character;
        }
        for character in &tetromino.second_line.characters {
            let x = character.x;
            let y = character.y;
            built_tetrominoes[y as usize][x as usize] = *character;
        }
        for character in &tetromino.third_line.characters {
            let x = character.x;
            let y = character.y;
            built_tetrominoes[y as usize][x as usize] = *character;
        }
        for character in &tetromino.fourth_line.characters {
            let x = character.x;
            let y = character.y;
            built_tetrominoes[y as usize][x as usize] = *character;
        }
    }
}

fn check_complete_line(
    built_tetrominoes: &mut [[TetrominoCharacter; WIDTH]; HEIGHT],
    score: &mut u32,
) -> bool {
    let mut complete_line = false;
    let mut lines_cleared = 0;

    for i in 0..HEIGHT {
        let mut line_is_complete = true;

        for j in 1..WIDTH - 1 {
            if built_tetrominoes[i][j].value.is_empty() {
                line_is_complete = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if line_is_complete {
            complete_line = true;
            lines_cleared += 1;

            // Clear the current line
            for j in 0..WIDTH {
                built_tetrominoes[i][j] = TetrominoCharacter::default();
            }

            // Shift all rows above the current line down by one row
            for k in (1..=i).rev() {
                for j in 0..WIDTH {
                    built_tetrominoes[k][j] = built_tetrominoes[k - 1][j];
                    // Move character down by one row
                    built_tetrominoes[k][j].move_character(0, 1);
                }
            }

            // Clear the top row since it has been shifted down
            for j in 0..WIDTH {
                built_tetrominoes[0][j] = TetrominoCharacter::default();
            }
        }
    }

    // Update score based on the number of lines cleared
    *score += lines_cleared * 100;

    complete_line
}

fn remake_gameborders(
    game_borders: &mut [[bool; WIDTH]; HEIGHT + 1],
    built_tetrominoes: &mut [[TetrominoCharacter; WIDTH]; HEIGHT],
) {
    for i in 0..HEIGHT {
        for j in 0..WIDTH {
            if built_tetrominoes[i][j].value.is_empty() {
                game_borders[i][j] = false;
            } else {
                game_borders[i][j] = true;
            }
        }
    }
}

I've already searched and tried to fix it, yet I can't seem to find a way to fix it.
I wanted the function to be appropriately called given that it is public and I'm using use crate::move_to_built to import it. However this didn't worked and I get an unresolved_import error

Do you have mod display; in lib.rs?

How does your Cargo.toml look like, and how do you run cargo when you get that error?

Care should be taken when using lib.rs and main.rs to avoid declaring the same module in both. It more than likely just causes confusion. Can you share any mod declarations in those files?

@ChayimFriedmanyes I do have it

@trueequalsfalse My cargo.toml looks like this: `[package]
name = "rust-tetris"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"
See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html
[dependencies]
rand = "0.8.5"
termion = "4.0.0"
and runningcargo buildshows:error[E0432]: unresolved import `crate::move_to_built``

@kmdreko I think I've taken care of this issue, I've updated the post with the main.rs and lib.rs, along with the mod declarations

You shouldn't have mod display in both lib.rs and main.rs. Instead you should have pub mod display in lib.rs and use rust_tetris::display in main.rs
